# Geth leveldb critical errors causing the sync process to stop. I have tried available fixes, does anyone know what might be happening?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I am trying to sync a geth node but keep getting fatal errors that crash the program during syncing. I looked up a few options on how to solve this but nothing has worked yet. I tried to delete and reinstall, remove my data dir, run `geth removedb`, but no progress yet. I am running on a linux machine (ubuntu 20.04) with a 1tb nvme drive and 32 gb of ram. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this and sync? Here is an example of the error below:

```
ERROR[07-21|20:33:50.988] Failed to persist stack slots  
err="leveldb/table: corruption on data-block (pos=963478): checksum mismatch, 
want=0xcb582269 got=0xc97d95c7 [file=002046.ldb]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been banging my head against this exact issue/error for the past 2 weeks and finally, yesterday, I solved it. I had one stick of 8GB RAM installed and it was faulty. I ran a memory test and it showed faults.

*(Steps for the Memory Test I ran)*

```
sudo apt install memtester
sudo memtester 7000M 1 (replace 7000 with the MB of Memory you have)
```

I replaced it with new RAM and the issue has stopped. I would seriously consider running a memory test and SMART HardDrive test to see if you are experiencing hardware failures.

I hope that helps!